Expo Document Picker not allowing to pick a document
I am using Expo with React Native for my app. upon clikcing on a button, i want the user to have the ability to upload multiple pdf files. I am using expo and the expo go app (on a physical device and on a simulator) to test code.
The issue now is that every time I want to open the Document Picker on IOS, I briefly see the document selector and then it disappears and I can't pick any documents.
This is the code I use:
try {
      const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type:'*/*',
        copyToCacheDirectory: true,
        multiple: false 
      });
      if (result.type === 'success') {
        console.log('Document picked:', result);
      } else {
        console.log('Document picking canceled');
      }
      console.log('result', JSON.stringify(result))
} catch (err) {
      console.log('error', err)
 
}

This is how my app.json file looks like:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My name",
    "scheme": "example-app",
    "slug": "example-app",
    "version": "1.0.11",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/resized_icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/logo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "icon": "./assets/logo_apple_format.png",
      "bundleIdentifier": "********",
      "usesIcloudStorage": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "Wir brauchen Zugriff auf den Ort, um die Applikation optimal laufen lassen zu können.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Wir brauchen Zugriff auf die Galerie, um Bilder für die Beantragung der Rückerstattung hochzuladen.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Wir brauchen Zugriff auf die Kamera, um Bilder für die Beantragung der Rückerstattung hochzuladen.",
        "NSDocumentPickerUsageDescription": "Wir brauchen Zugriff auf die Dokumente, um Dokumente hochzuladen für die Beantragung der Rückerstattung."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/resized_icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "packageid",
      "versionCode": 11,
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/resized-icon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-firebase/auth",
      [
        "expo-document-picker",
        {
          "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static",
            "deploymentTarget": "13.4"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "*********"
      }
    },
    "owner": "*********"
  }
}

I have followed the documentation to the best of my abilities and yet the document picker doesn't work on a physical ios device or on a simulator.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: I have tested it further and found out that the issue is that i call the function within a modal. Outside of it, it works. How can I make it work within a modal?
